# Can "My girl" also be used to refer to my daughter?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, formality, phrase-usage

I today accidentally used "My girl is 5 months old" and I meant to refer to my daughter in this sentence. In the given context it does sound like what I meant to say but wanted to know if it can really be used that way.
Again, can "My Girl" be used to refer either girlfriend/wife or daughter depending on context?
Also can this be used in formal meetings/conversations?

Comment: Yes, 'my girl' can mean daughter.  Context is king!

Comment: In a "formal" context (if I thought about it at all, and actually had a daughter), I'd probably say "_My daughter_" over "_My girl_", but that's because of formality rather than to avoid confusion (in such a context, "_My girl_" probably wouldn't be the correct words for a girlfriend/wife/partner either).

Comment: However, "My little girl" would be understood correctly.

Comment: If you have a baby, that's not your girlfriend, so where would confusion enter?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. My little girl do sound like best choice in this case.

Comment: Actually, I think "my little girl" would be a lot more clear...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without context, *my girl* is ambiguous. For instance, it used to be a common way for executives to refer to their secretaries (watch "Mad Men" and you'll probably hear Don Draper use the term that way). There's the classic Temptations song ["My Girl"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Girl_(The_Temptations_song)), which was about the songwriter's wife. And in the Eddie Murphy song ["Party All the Time"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Party_All_the_Time) the main lyric uses the phrase to refer to the singer's girlfriend.

But once you mention the girl's age, it's unlikely to be misunderstood. A 5-month-old can't be a wife, girlfriend, or assistant, so it must be a daughter.

And I think the plural *my girls* would usually be understood to mean your daughters, unless you're in a specific context where there's some other expectation. For instance, the owner/manager/coach of a women's sports team might refer to the team this way, although it would probably be considered demeaning these days. Or a teacher in an all-girl school could refer to their students this way.

A clearer term might be "my little girl".

Comment: +1 "My girls" seems to be a very common way for parents to refer to their daughters collectively, especially (it seems to me) if they only have daughters. On the other hand, I also hear it occasionally to refer to a man's daughter or daughters and *wife*, but I think the context would make this clear.

Answer (score -1):

I think girl can't be my wife  Ican say  my girl like my daughter
so if girl  can be Girlfriend I can't say My Girl like Daughter.

Comment: Your answer is contradictory. It helps if you write clear sentences and back up the information that you give with a bit of research. This is how this site works